# photoshop cs6 reflection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, reflection

How can I make reflection like on [this](https://dgrisogono.s3.amazonaws.com/dgweb/HJ-Home.png) image? With this amazing blur effect?

For now I can make only simple vertical reflection following this steps:
 1. Copy layer and put the copy under the main layer
 2. Transformation -> Flip vertically
 3. Add some gradient

But it makes only simple vertical reflection. How can I make such a beautiful amazing reflection exactly like on the [example above](https://dgrisogono.s3.amazonaws.com/dgweb/HJ-Home.png)?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. If you want to know more about the site, please see [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Is that picture natural (taken by a camera) or painted (drawn digitally or something)?

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be a custom made reflection.

Make a new layer, brush some color spots in it. Add a gaussian blur and some noise et voila.
Try experimenting with those.